float values not displaying decimal places when using pandas to_sql()
I am inserted values into a table using df.to_sql() function, but the values are not being displayed properly in SQL Server.
At the top of my script I use:
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format

and when I print my dataframes all is well:
 Value    Price
100.0000   34.0100
101.4000   35.0100
102.0000   36.0100
103.9000   37.0100
104.0000   38.0100    

however, when I insert into SQL Server I get:
Value    Price
100      34.01
101.4    35.01
102      36.01
103.9    37.01
104      38.01  

This is what I have tried:
df.to_sql('table', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={"Price": Float(), "Value": Float()})

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix? I am using SQLAlchemy and SQL Server

What's your SQL table definition?

@DaleK  the price and value column have a float datatype

@DaleK I don't explicitly define a table definition since I the to_sql() function in pandas with infer column types when creating a table. But I do explicitly define the data types for the those columns in the piece of code above

I'm not sure the problem you're having. It's almost like you think that input format is being kept when adding values. Try inserting 000001 and see what gets stored

@siggemannen I want to keep the decimal precision after I insert the data into sql server from pandas

Float doesn't have precision, it's just an approximation data type. You'll need numeric for that. I'm no panda expert, but i don't think pd.options.display.float_format actually controls the storage, only how it's shown when you print the values

And you want to think very carefully before using a float data type, because it's only approximate. You normally want decimal or numeric

You would have to format the value to 4 decimal places in your SQL query. Floats don't store trailing zeroes after decimal point.

As @siggemannen and @DaleK mentioned, Float does not have precision and is an approximation data type. Numeric is the option to go with for fixed precision:
from sqlalchemy.types import Numeric

df.to_sql('CounterpartyData', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={"Price": Numeric(19,4), "Value": Numeric(19,4)})

Output in SQL:
Value    Price
100.0000   34.0100
101.4000   35.0100
102.0000   36.0100
103.9000   37.0100
104.0000   38.0100 

